# Google sheets: Return values from a span of control that are not specific values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

In Google Sheets:

I have a master database sheet tab where I have fields specific to individuals (Worker number, preferred full name, manager, and job status). I have created formulas where I can pull the manager of a manager and so on, up to the highest reporting level. Now I am trying to create a formula that returns the highest reporting layer's name, but NOT certain individuals.

The issue I am running into is, the reporting layers are different per person. For some individuals, they may only have 3 layers to the highest level; other individuals may have up-to 10 layers to the highest level.

In the screenshot example, I would want the "Head" column to return the name of the highest layer person, but NOT "Name 1" or "Name 2" regardless of whatever layer they are in for that row.

[image: current view]

I was able to pull the next layer name with the following formula (adjusting the match based on Col C):

```
=ifna(index($C:$C,match(C4,$B:$B,0)),"")
```

I attempted to pull the correct layer, without the specific name with the following formula, but I can't seem to be able to replicate this for multiple folks to be removed:

```
=ifs(INDEX($B2:$M2,COUNTA($B2:$M2)-1)="Name 1",(INDEX($B2:$M2,COUNTA($B2:$M2)-2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XLOOKUP to achieve what I think you're expecting to get. Adapt it to your ranges:

```
=XLOOKUP("*",A2:J2,$A$1:$J$1,"No name",2,-1)
```

Inside XLOOKUP, the asterisk finds any character (not empty cell). A2:J2 is the row with the names, $A$1:$J$1 is the header. "No name" appears when all the row is empty. "2" allows you to use the asterisk as a wildcard. And -1 does the searching from right to left

[image]